# Cannot find class mentioned under classname in ANT's Build.xml

Tags: java, xml, ant, classpath, build.xml

I have below code snippet in build.xml file of my project.

```
 <taskdef name="SomeTask" classname="com.abc.myproject.SomeClass">
            <classpath refid="misc.Some.classpath" />
 </taskdef>
```

For some debugging purpose, I need to find this "com.abc.efg.SomeClass".
I tried to look for this class in my entire project code and in all referred jar's availble.

And as I am new to ANT, I googled about this "taskdef" which explains that it makes a task called SomeTask available to Apache Ant. The class com.abc.efg.SomeClass implements the task.

But I could not find this class in my project.

I just want to know that from what all places we can be referring this class.
And also by looking at the complete class name, it looks like that this class is not java in built class and belong to my project only.

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The task implementation class must be contained in the ant classpath defined by the path id `misc.Some.classpath`.

Search your ant file and any included ant files or properties for the path definition with that id (i.e. grep for `misc.Some.classpath`). If you opened the ant file in Eclipse you can even jump to the definition by using CTRL+Click on the id.

The path definition should then reveal the locations (jars, directories) where you can find the task class.